# Redux structure for dynamic components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a application which allows users to add components (widgets) which means they can set certain filtering on that widget specifically or use a global filter which is set application wide. I have two questions:

- How do I create the state for these dynamic components? I can't wrap my head around how I would even start to think about this so its more a little bit of direction is required.
- Allowing components to use either the global filter state or isolate the widget and set filtering for that component specifically.

To give an example for context, the dynamic widgets are used in a dashboard and at the moment they are static tables, graphs etc which pull data from 1/2 endpoints and have a static state structure, and filtering is in the from on a date picker which allows you to specify a range to return data for. The next iteration requires the dashboard to have widgets which are added by the user and each widget could have its own date picker and pull from a separate endpoint if the user wants that.

Comment: I understand this is a little vague, but I just require some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per-component state in the store is an area of open exploration in the Redux community.  If you look at the [Component State](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/component-state.md) page of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links), you'll see at least a dozen different libraries which approach the problem in different ways.  You should probably be able to use one of them to solve your use case, or at least serve as an inspiration.